# Having LaTeX equation in LyX numbered equation

Tags: equations, lyx

I have a LaTeX Equation that I am trying to insert in my LyX document as in the attached image[image: Equation in LyX]
So, I Click Ctrl+L to insert TeX code inside that numbered equation but it doesn't work.
It only works when I Enter the LaTeX equation in the TeX Code (Ctrl+L) but outside the numbered equation (that is shown in the image).
Is there a way I can work around it to have TeX Code inside a numbered equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste the LaTeX equation directly into the box for a numbered equation without using Ctrl+L. I often write the equation in an online GUI or MathType, then copy the equation directly into Lyx's numbered equation.

Comment: I tried it but the symbols of the LaTeX doesn't work on LyX

Comment: You are actually right, I have to copy what's between the dolar signs $ and directly paste it in the numbered equation in LyX.
Thank you.